# Is there a log4net appender for generating an administrator view-the-guts page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, log4net

So I've put a lot of effort into setting up solid meaningful logging in my web app. By looking at my log.log file it is possible to get all sorts of info about what went wrong and what went right.

It would be really nice now if I could take that and turn it into a page on my site that will show all that stuff nicely formatted to administrators. I realize that I'd have to implement authentication and authorization myself but surely someone has built an open source appender or at least a simple log viewer that can generate the actual page?

Does anyone know of anything?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a XML appender and then apply a XSLT transformation to transform the log file into a human readable HTML. Here's a [blog post](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DesktopDev/MSTech/making-an-xmllayout-for-log4net).

Comment: +1 But this really seems unnecessarily complex. Is this not a common thing for people using log4net to do?